# Android Studio Gradle task to rename libraries

Tags: android, gradle, rename

I have some problems in that the regular Android Studio build process does not want to bundle native libraries whose name starts with an underscore. I've tried the following option, but without success:

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
    }
}
```

So now, I'm trying an approach where I rename `_foo.so` to `foo.so`, so that the build process picks it up, but right before the apk gets built, I want to rename these back to _foo.so.

Looking at the Gradle tasks that get called when building an apk, I wanted my task to run after `mergeDebugNativeLibs`. An (incomplete) draft of my code looks like this:

```
task renameLibraries (type: Copy, dependsOn: mergeDebugNativeLibs) {
    from ('build/intermediates/merged_jni_libs/debug/out/x86_64/')
    into ('build/intermediates/merged_jni_libs/debug/out/x86_64/')
    include '*.cpython-37m.so'
    rename { String filename -> "_" + filename }
}
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'mergeDebugNativeLibs' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Open File
```

Can anyone help me to achieve what I want?

Comment: Put the task in `afterEvaluate`?

Comment: Gives the same error...